# How do I add a DLL as a reference on .Net C++ Project using Visual Studio

Tags: c++, dll

I know on VB or C# .Net I just right click on references and browse to the DLL, but I don't have this on Visual C++.

Do I need to do this programmatically or can I do it from the IDE?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using a DLL in Visual Studio C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/988334/using-a-dll-in-visual-studio-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right-click your project, select "Properties". In the tree on the left side on the dialog, navigate to "Common Properties" -> "Framework and References", where you will find the "Add New Reference" button.